# Selenium Firefox profile not found

Tags: php, firefox, selenium, webdriver, profile

I just started learning selenium on a Linux server. I would start by opening two putty terminals and change directory to where my files are.

So, In **terminal 1** - Starting the server, I would run this command:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar  selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=SeleniumTest
```

Then, In **terminal 2** - Running the test script, I would run this command:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit SeleniumTestUpload.php
```

As you can see,  I have defined the firefox profile **SeleniumTest** and *this works perfectly fine*.

Now, I have decided to make selenium standalone server to be a Linux service, So I can proceed immediately to running my test script. I found the resources to make one and I was able to make it running.

The problem now is when I execute my test script, I get the error:

```
 UnknownServerException: Firefox profile 'SeleniumTest' named in system property 'webdriver.firefox.profile' not found
```

But, If i do not define a profile, It would continue on. May I know what is causing this? Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright! After many head scratches,  I added this line on the service script: `export HOME='/root'`. I hope this help someone on the future ;)